# Align fixContent centered in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

Here is a minimalistic example:

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App"
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
displayBlock="true">
<App>
    <pages>
        <Page title="Home"
        width="100%" height="100%">
            <content>
                <l:FixFlex
                    class="sapUiTinyMarginTopBottom"
                    vertical="false"
                    minFlexSize="1"
                    fixFirst="false">
                    <l:flexContent>
                        <List
                            width="100%"
                            showSeparators="Inner">
                            <items>
                                <StandardListItem text="Row 1"/>
                                <StandardListItem text="Row 2"/>
                                <StandardListItem text="Row 3"/>
                            </items>
                        </List>
                    </l:flexContent>
                    <l:fixContent
                        class="sapUiTinyMarginTopBottom"
                        height="100%">

                        <Button icon="sap-icon://add" press="onPress">
                            <layoutData>
                                <FlexItemData alignSelf="Center"></FlexItemData>
                            </layoutData>
                        </Button>

                        </l:fixContent>
                </l:FixFlex>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

I want to have the Button aligned in the Center and not at the top auf the box/layout.

Is FixFlex layout the right one?
Important for me is that I want to have multiple lists one above the over so they have the same size (they are in table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FixFlex is used to split up the space between two areas: the `fix` one which has a fixed dimension and the `flex` one which is flexible and will take up the rest of the space.

If your goal is to have the List to fill up the remaining space on the screen and the button to have a fixed width, then it is ok to use it. For aligning the button in the center (vertically), I don't think that the FixFlex will help you that much. One idea would be to surround the button in a FlexBox:

```
<HBox height="100%" alignItems="Center">
    <Button icon="sap-icon://add" press="onPress" />
</HBox>
```

You can see a working version of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/amnswh85/1/

Another option would be to ditch the FixFlex completely and use just a FlexBox and play around with the `growFactor` of each item:

```
<HBox width="100%" alignItems="Stretch"> 
    <List width="100%" showSeparators="Inner">
      <items>
        <StandardListItem title="Row 1" />
        <StandardListItem title="Row 2" />
        <StandardListItem title="Row 3" />
      </items>
      <layoutData>
         <FlexItemData growFactor="1"/>
      </layoutData>
    </List>
    <Button icon="sap-icon://add" press="onPress">
      <layoutData>
         <FlexItemData alignSelf="Center"/>
      </layoutData>
    </Button>
</HBox>
```

You can find a working version of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/amnswh85/

Comment: The second one worked for me within an table. Thanks a lot!